# insert doctrine in custom service symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, persist

I have a problem using doctrine into the service :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function persist() on a non-object in /var/www/Symfony/src/mio/mioBundle/AuthenticationHandler.php on line 37

the code the service is:

```
services:
    authentication_handler:
        class: mio\mioBundle\AuthenticationHandler
        arguments: [@router , @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

the code the listener is:

```
class AuthenticationHandler extends ContainerAware implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface{

    protected $router;

    protected $em;

        public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }


     public function __constructor(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $empleado = $token->getUser();
        $empleado->setNombre("abeeeer");
        $this->em->persist($empleado); //line 37
        $this->em->flush();

        //return new Response($token->getUsername());
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('familia'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have more than one parameters in a constructor:

```
public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

But you can't have several constructors in a class and `__constructor` is not a constructor method name, so you should remove that method.

Also, you don't have to extend `ContainerAware` because you're injecting the services you need anyway. It means you don't need this:

```
calls:
    - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```